# Registro de nombres y teléfonos sin bases de datos en php

Tags: php

Tengo una duda, tengo que hacer una aplicación (SIN USAR BASES DE DATOS) en la cual, cuando ingrese un nombre y un número de teléfono me vaya agregando todos esos nombres a la tabla. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<?php

$arrayValues = [];
$name = $telephone = "";
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
  $telephone = test_input($_POST["telephone"]);
  $arrayValues[$name] = $telephone;
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripcslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>
  <h1>App-Agenda</h1>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Nº de teléfono</th>
      </tr>
<?php
  echo "<tr>";
  if (
       !empty($_POST['name']
    && !empty($_POST['telephone']))
  ) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
    foreach($arrayValues as $name => $telephone) {
      echo "<td>".$name."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$telephone."</td>";
    }
  }
  echo "</tr>";
?>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <h2>Formulario</h2>
  <form method="post"
    action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] );?>">
    Nombre: <input type="text" name="name">
    <br><br>
    Nº de teléfono: <input type="number" name="telephone">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar">
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Lo he intentado con el foreach que me recorra el array de valores, pero no lo consigo. Si alguien me puede ayudar, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

En forms HTML podes almacenar arrays agregandole al name del input el par de corchetes `[]` .

Es decir para enviarte un array o grupo de `<input name="telefono"` con varios `values` pones varios inputs con los distintos valores y el mismo `name` :

```html
<form method=post>
<input type="text" name="nombre[]" value="a" /><br/>
<input type="text" name="nombre[]" value="b" /><br/>
<input type="text" name="nombre[]" value="c" /><br/>
<br/>
<input type="text" name="nombre[]" /><br/>
<input type="submit" name="agregar" value="Agregar">
</form>
```

Este array se guarda en el `$_POST['nombre']` sin los `[]`

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);

$names = $_POST['name'];
```

```
Array
(
  [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => c
            [3] => nuevo valor
        )
  [agregar] => Agregar
)
```

Así es que podemos "recordar" el estado del array en cada "post", si queremos evitar que se editen usamos campos ocultos, e imprimimos el valor solamente.

Por ej:

```html
<form method=post>
<input type="hidden" name="nombre[]" value="a" />a<br/>
<input type="hidden" name="nombre[]" value="b" />b<br/>
<input type="hidden" name="nombre[]" value="c" />c<br/>
<br/>
<input type="text" name="nombre[]" /><br/>
<input type="submit" name="agregar" value="Agregar">
</form>
```

Con la función `array_map` podemos convertir los 2 arrays ( nombre y telefonos ) en un sólo array con nombre y telefono por cada línea, "omitiendo" los pares incompletos.

```php
// capturamos los arrayes, default es array vacío -> []
$names = $_POST["name"] ?? [];
$telephones = $_POST["telephone"] ?? [];

// mapeamos los arrayes
$arrayForm = array_map(
  function ($n, $t) {
    // limpiamos campos
    $clean_n = test_input($n);
    $clean_t = test_input($t);
    // sólo si ambos contienen algo
    if (
      '' !== $clean_n
      && '' !== $clean_t
    )
      return [
        'name' => $clean_n,
        'telephone' => $clean_t
      ];
  },
  $names,
  $telephones
);
```

Si alguno de los campos del par está vacío nos queda un "agujero" en el array resultante, asi que usamos `array_filter` sin filtro para que el array final tenga sólo pares completos.

```
// quitamos entradas vacías
// aqui se descartan campos vacíos del "agregar"
$arrayValues = array_filter($arrayForm);
```

Ya con esto podemos recorrer el array e imprimirlo por pantalla, pero como bonus vamos a agregar un "boton de quitar" que va a ser un input que incluya el  indice del array del par que queremos quitar ( en realidad evitamos imprimir ese par para que no se envíe en el siguiente post)

```php
if (!empty($arrayValues)) {
  foreach ($arrayValues as $index => $value) {
    $quitarBtnName = "quitar{$index}";
    // sólo uncluir el par si el "boton" no existe en POST
    // si existe es que se está quitando este par

    if (!isset($_POST[$quitarBtnName])) {
      ?>
...
  <input type="submit" name="<?php echo $quitarBtnName; ?>" value="quitar">
...
      <?php
    } // cierre quitar
  } // cierre foreach
} // cierre hay values
```

Todo junto y con un espacio para ver las variables mediante `print_r` quedaría así:

`agenda_form.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <style>
    pre {
      font-size: small; overflow-y: scroll;
      width: 33vw; border: 1px #ccc solid;
      padding: 5px; margin: 5px;
      position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    }

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <pre>
  <?php
  print_r($_POST ?? []);

  $arrayValues = [];

  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // capturamos los arrayes; default array vacío -> []
    $names = $_POST["name"] ?? [];
    $telephones = $_POST["telephone"] ?? [];

    // mapeamos los arrayes
    $arrayForm = array_map(
      function ($n, $t) {
        // limpiamos
        $clean_n = test_input($n);
        $clean_t = test_input($t);
        // si ambos contienen algo
        if (
          '' !== $clean_n
          && '' !== $clean_t
        )
          return [
            'name' => $clean_n,
            'telephone' => $clean_t
          ];
      },
      $names,
      $telephones
    );

    // quitamos entradas vacías
    // aqui se descartan campos vacíos del agregar
    $arrayValues = array_filter($arrayForm);

    print_r([
      '$names' => $names,
      '$telephones' => $telephones,
      '$arrayForm' => $arrayForm,
      '$arrayValues' => $arrayValues,
    ]);
  }

  function test_input($data)
  {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripcslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
  }
  ?>
  </pre>
  <h1>App-arrayValues</h1>
  <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Nº de teléfono</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        if (!empty($arrayValues)) {
          foreach ($arrayValues as $index => $value) {
            $name = $value['name'];
            $telephone = $value['telephone'];
            $quitarBtnName = "quitar{$index}";
            // sólo uncluir el par si el "boton" no existe en POST
            // si existe es que se está quitando este par
        
            if (!isset($_POST[$quitarBtnName])) {
              ?>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <input type="hidden" name="name[]" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" />
                  <?php echo $name; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input type="hidden" name="telephone[]" value="<?php echo $telephone;?>">
                  <?php echo $telephone; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input type="submit" name="<?php echo $quitarBtnName; ?>" value="quitar">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <?php
            } // cierre quitar
          } // cierre foreach
        } // cierre hay values
        ?>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h2>Formulario</h2>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="name[]" /></td>
          <td><input type="number" name="telephone[]"></td>
          <td><input type="submit" name="agregar" value="Agregar"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Hay varios errores lógicos en este código.

1- En la parte que tratas de imprimir la tabla, si observas estás imprimiendo lo que mandaste vía POST, no la variable que debe acumular los registros `$arrayValues`.

2- La estructura acumulativa `$arrayValues` se está cargando de la siguiente forma: `array(String nombre => String telefono)`. Esto hará que cada vez que quieras meter un nuevo contacto a la agenda se sobreescriba, por lo que siempre tendrá 1 solo registro. La estructura debería ser:

```txt
[
  ['name'=>'Juan Pérez', 'telephone'=>'12345'],
  ['name'=>'Jorge García', 'telephone'=>'56789'],
  ...
]
```

3- Cuando le das clic al botón "Enviar", el script se vuelve a ejecutar desde el principio y todas las variables "mueren" por lo que pierdes el valor de `$arrayValues`. Obviamente, la mejor forma de resolver esto es ... *usando Base de Datos*. 
En tu caso no puedes usar, entonces lo que debes hacer es tratar de re-enviar la data que ya existe en `$arrayValues` para seguir usándola en la siguiente ejecución. Una forma puede ser usando [sesiones](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.session.php), o la otra es enviando el array vía `POST` desde el formulario.
En este caso usaré la 2da opción. Pero no se puede enviar un array así por así, primero hay que [serializarlo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14071733/1545868) y cuando lo captures de des-serializa.

```php
<?php
    $arrayValues = [];
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $arrayValues = unserialize($_POST['arrayValues']);
        $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
        $telephone = test_input($_POST["telephone"]);
        $arrayValues[] = ['name'=>$name, 'telephone'=>$telephone];
    }

    function test_input($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripcslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }
?>
<h1>App-Agenda</h1>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Nº de teléfono</th>
        </tr>
    <thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        foreach($arrayValues as $row) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['telephone'];?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

<h2>Formulario</h2>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="arrayValues" value="<?php echo htmlentities(serialize($arrayValues));?>">
    Nombre: <input type="text" name="name">
    <br><br>
    Nº de teléfono: <input type="number" name="telephone">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```